# Supermartingale and stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Let suppose there is a sequence of random variables $(X_n)_n$, with some $X_0 \gg 1$ being a constant and $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2 | X_{n-1}) = f(X_{n-1})$, where $f(X_{n-1}) < X_{n-1}^2$, while $X_{n-1} > 2$. We know $\mathbb{E}(X_n) < \infty$ and even $X_n < X_0 + n$ a.s.

For example, $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2 | X_{n-1}) = X_{n-1}^2 - X_{n-1}$.

> This somehow resembles supermartingale, but is it?

From $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2 | X_{n-1}) = f(X_{n-1})$

> What is the rigorous way to get to $\mathbb{E}(X_n | X_{n-1})$ ?

What I mean, is there any general procedure/algorithm, which given $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2 | X_{n-1}) = f(X_{n-1})$ produces $g(X_{n-1})$, s.t. $\mathbb{E}(X_n | X_{n-1}) = g(X_{n-1})$.

Let suppose this is possible and $(X_n)_n$ is supermartingale.

Let $\tau = \inf \{n: X_n < 2\}$.

> How can I find $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$? i.e. is there any useful "Optional Stopping Theorem", or are "Wald's-like identities" extremely problem specific?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. By definition, a (super)martingale must be integrable, i.e. we must have $\mathbb E[X_n^2]<\infty$ (which is a stronger condition than $\mathbb E[|X_n|]<\infty]$). What do you mean by "rigorous way to get to $\mathbb E[X_n\mid X_{n-1}]$"? What do you mean by "estimating" $\mathbb E[\tau]$?

Comment: I've added some more info. Is it a bit more clear now? Note, that what actually interests me, is $(X_n)_n$ to be (super)martingale, so why $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)$ is of interest?